# Ruby only executing the first line?

Tags: ruby, shell, exec

I'm writing a ruby script and found this strange behaviour.

Using `ruby 2.4.2 [x86_64-darwin16]`

Basically I'm trying to echo two separated messages and in my `index.rb` file I got:

```
exec("echo 'teste'")
exec("echo 'teste2'")
```

But when I run `ruby ./index.rb`

The output is:

```
teste
```

Why that's happening?

Shouldn't this be the output?

```
testeteste2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `exec([env,] command... [,options])`
>
> Replaces the current process by running the given external command [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Kernel.html#method-i-exec)

It means that the first call to `exec` replaces your ruby program with `echo`, so the rest of the ruby program is not executed.

You can use backticks to run a command like you want:

```
`echo 'teste'`
`echo 'teste2'`
```

Comment: makes sense, there's a way to go back to the original script?

Comment: nope, you can't go back, you need to use another way of calling a system command

Comment: Is there a good reason why you need to call `exec`, at all? One would normally use `puts` or `print` to output text to STDOUT, rather than making an external call.

Comment: acually I'm dealing with shell scripts, for writing files and packing things

Comment: @PedroSturmer Again -- The normal way to do all of this (*in ruby*) is to [write the file with ruby](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rubyworks/facets/File.write), not external shell scripts. Of course there are exceptions to the rule, but I cannot advise without more context.

Comment: ...But if you really do want to make external system calls, rather than actually writing ruby, you're probably looking for [`system` or `Open3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5970819/1954610) instead of `exec`.

Comment: As a note, while backticks work, they're really far from ideal as you have very little control over how the shell interprets the arguments. `system()` and as Tom points out `Open3` give way more control and assurances that things like spaces in filenames won't cause chaos.