# Parse a system function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am doing `pdfinfo` in my system function and I want to only get the page size `612 x 1008` but I am not sure how to parse it out.

my code

```
output = system("pdfinfo example.docx_ms.pdf")
print "#{output} \n"
x = "612x1008"
puts x

if x == output
 puts "yes"
else
 puts "no"
end
```

output

```
612 x 1008
true
```

Comment: I'd avoid the external dependency and use a Ruby PDF library like [pdf-reader](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [backticks or %x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18623297/544825) instead of system to capture the output:

```
output = `pdfinfo example.docx_ms.pdf | grep 'Page size:'`
puts output.gsub(/Page size:\s*\b/, '').chomp
```

---

```
irb(main):001:0> `pdfinfo example.docx_ms.pdf | grep 'Page size:'`.gsub(/Page size:\s*\b/, '').chomp
=> "595 x 842 pts (A4)"
```

Comment: I am getting a `undefined method 'gsub' for true:TrueClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Are you using backticks or system? I initially made a copy paste error and used system (which returns true/false).

Comment: awesome this worked, But could you explain what `Page size:\s*\b/` does?

Comment: gsub replaces the pattern with the second argument. `\s*` matches 0 or more spaces. `\b` matches a word boundry and I guess its actually kind of redundant when I think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Using answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2360482), You can do this

```rb
output = `pdfinfo example.docx_ms.pdf | grep 'Page size:' | awk '{ print $3 $4 $5} '`.chomp
print "#{output} \n"
```

What this does is

1. Return document details as provided by `pdfinfo`
2. String match the line wanted using grep ie `Page size`
3. Using `awk` to filter the page size dimensions.

You can read more about [grep](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/grep-command-in-unixlinux/) and [awk](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/awk-command-unixlinux-examples/)

[image]

Comment: awesome thank you! my output is `612x1008
true` I have an if-statement i've added to compare the outputs and it is coming back as `false` I've updated my code in the question

Comment: @tintin the if statement will not work unless you extract  `Page size` dimensions from pdfinfo result. right now you are comparing the X variable with pdfinfo result.

Comment: how would I be able to do that? Aren't we already getting the dimensions?

Comment: This prints the output, it doesn't capture it. You'll need [Open3](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Open3.html) for that. It's also kind of backwards to use `grep` and `awk` when Ruby can do all of that and more internally. If the output needs parsing `readlines.grep` is a good start.