How to introduce a filename into shell script in Ruby script
Ruby script where I want to run a shell script and pass in a filename with spaces. I've tried a dozen ways of doing. Here's one:
filename = "/Users/gscar/Pictures/_Photo Processing Folders/Watched folder for import to Photos/2024.03.25-16.09.59.gs.O.orf"
filename = filename.gsub(' ', '\ ')
'exiftool -Camera:DriveMode #{filename}'

Other include hard coding the path
result = %x{exiftool -Camera:DriveMode /Users/gscar/Pictures/_Photo\ Processing\ Folders/Watched\ folder\ for\ import\ to\ Photos/2024.03.25-16.09.59.gs.O.orf}

which results in

8 files could not be read

and
system 'exiftool -Camera:DriveMode "/Users/gscar/Pictures/_Photo Processing Folders/Watched folder for import to Photos/2024.03.25-16.09.59.gs.O.orf"'

with no output.
Command line
➜ exiftool -Camera:DriveMode "/Users/gscar/Pictures/_Photo Processing Folders/Watched folder for import to Photos/2024.03.25-16.09.59.gs.O.orf"
Drive Mode                      : Single Shot; Electronic shutter

Command line with escaped spaces works
➜ exiftool -Camera:DriveMode /Users/gscar/Pictures/_Photo\ Processing\ Folders/Watched\ folder\ for\ import\ to\ Photos/2024.03.25-16.09.59.gs.O.orf
Drive Mode                      : Single Shot; Electronic shutter

What I need eventually is for this something like this to work. The above is trying to figure out how to get the filename working:
filename = "/Users/gscar/Pictures/_Photo Processing Folders/Watched folder for import to Photos/2024.03.25-16.09.59.gs.O.orf"
gsubfilename = filename.gsub(' ', '\ ')
`"exiftool -Camera:DriveMode #{gsubfilename}"`

and the result is:
sh: exiftool -Camera:DriveMode /Users/gscar/Pictures/_Photo\ Processing\ Folders/Watched\ folder\ for\ import\ to\ Photos/2024.03.25-16.09.59.gs.O.orf: No such file or directory

but of course running this in shell works fine.
What is "escaping" me here? Thanks
PS mini_exiftool doesn't seem to handle "DriveMode."

Have you considered using Open3 instead? Or at least the multi-argument form of system? If you don't use a shell then you don't have to worry about escaping things from the shell and there's no reason to invoke a shell to run something for you when you can run it directly without a shell.

The issue you’re encountering is due to the way Ruby handles backslashes in strings. When you use gsub to replace spaces with \ , Ruby interprets the backslash as an escape character, not a literal backslash.
To fix this, you can use double backslashes (\ ) in your gsub call

@mu is too short. I don't completely understand what you're saying. Is Open3 or system not running in shell? Anyway I tried this:
puts "\n#{LINE}. Open3 demo to make sure Open3 is available and it was"
stdout_s, status = Open3.capture2('echo "Foo"')
puts "\n#{LINE}. Open3 in action for filename"
stdout_s, status = Open3.capture2(exiftool -Camera:DriveMode "#{filename}")
puts "stdout_s: #{stdout_s}status: #{status}"
Result:

Open3 in action for filename
sh: Drive: command not found
sh: Electronic: command not found
stdout_s: status: pid 7652 exit 127


Don't build a command line as a string. For example: system('exiftool', '-Camera:DriveMode', filename). Similar approaches work with Open3. If you do it like that then you won't launch a shell and you won't have to deal with the shell's quoting and escaping problems, see the docs I linked to above.

@muistooshort I agree, but a nitpick: there are no real problems with shell's quoting and escaping, as long as you don't try to homebrew it. It is a solved problem. Just like you shouldn't try to write CSV without CSV module's help, you shouldn't access MySQL without an MySQL adapter gem, in the same way you shouldn't use gsub to escape shell arguments, but rather delegate the task to the proper library. The only issue is, just like with SQL, if you rely on escaping, you can forget to escape, and thus introduce a bug/vulnerability. This makes the no-shell safer against programmer error.

OP: Backticked cmd is an almost-synonym for system("cmd"). By placing backticks inside Open3.capture2, you were first executing exiftool, then passing the output of exiftool as the command for Open3.capture2 to execute. This is why you got the error: the output of exiftool is not a string describing an executable command, and when you try to run it as one, you get garbage.

@Amadan Didn't see the backtick problem in OP's Open3.capture2 example because they weren't escaped from Markdown. Speaking of escaping problems...

@muistooshort :D You are quite correct. Actually I still don't know how to correctly markdown "backtick - cmd - backtick".

As comments suggest, the best way is to avoid the shell, and invoke the command with arguments in an array. Specifically, for system, if you give at least one argument besides the program name to the function, the shell is not invoked.
system('exiftool', '-Camera:DriveMode', filename)

In this way, Ruby directly calls exiftool, and passes the given arguments to it. Since shell is not involved, you can't have parameter expansion (e.g. system('ls', '*') will complain that there are no files named *).

If you really really want to delegate argument parsing to the shell, use Shellwords, which knows how to escape shell arguments correctly:
require 'Shellwords'

system("exiftool -Camera:DriveMode #{filename.shellescape}")

Invoked this way, system will invoke $SHELL (e.g. /bin/sh), and ask it to execute the passed string. The shell will then process the string like it normally would, splitting it into command and arguments, performing parameter substitutions and everything else the shell does before executing the command. Thus, system('ls *') does what you would expect: lists the files in the current directory (because shell would have expanded * into multiple arguments before invoking ls).

Thank you both @mu is too short  @Amadan. To summarize for my benefit:
system('exiftool', '-Camera:DriveMode', filename). Doesn't launch a shell and you won't have to deal with the shell's quoting and escaping problems.
If you give at least one argument besides the program name to the function, the shell is not invoked.
Although I have to admit I don't understand why this avoids shell's escaping problems, but getting through shell, subshell, command_line, etc. In other words, many words I don't fully comprehend. system, https://ruby-doc.org/3.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system

If the shell is not invoked, the parameters are passed directly. For example, a space is just a space. 'foo bar' is a single argument. If a shell is invoked, shell is responsible for parsing; 'foo bar' is two arguments, a space is there to separate arguments, and if you want to include space inside an argument, you either need to use some additional quoting ('"foo bar"'), or escape the argument ('foo\\ bar'). shellescape does this for you.

To complete the answers from @mu is too short and @Amadan
driveMode = system('exiftool', '-Camera:DriveMode', fn) 

returns true or false which is covered in [system][1] which is not what I was looking for.
So the complete answer needs to include how to capture the value. Long discussion and suggestions [here][2]. This worked for me:
      r, w = IO.pipe
      system('exiftool', '-Camera:DriveMode', fn, out: w)
      w.close
      driveMode = r.read


  [1]: https://ruby-doc.org/current/Kernel.html#method-i-system
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690151/getting-output-of-system-calls-in-ruby

